# Regular expression to parse url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression in Javascript where:

```
/something/:workspaceId/somethingelse/:userId/blah/:id
```

Is parsed so that I get an array with `['workspaceId', 'userId', 'id']`.

Initial test:

```
p.match(/:.*?\/+/g )
```

This only matches the first two, workspaceId and userId.

This feels like a bit of a hack:

```
(p + '/').match(/:.*?\/+/g )
```

And it still returns `:workspaceId` rather than `workspaceId`.

Trying to fix it with whatI think the brackets should be for:

```
(p + '/').match(/:(.*)?\/+/g )
```

This last one really ought to work, but won't (since there are brackets, I expect the regexp only to return the match in the brackets).

At the moment, I am doing:

```
r = (p + '/').match(/:.*?\/+/g).map( function(i){return i.substr(1, i.length - 2 )  } );
```

But I would love to get something that:

1) Doesn't add that '/' at the end (although I could live with it)

2) It doesn't use the expensive map() method to do something the regexp should be doing in the first place

Comment: Try: `/:\w+/`.. learn regex pls. You should provide your own regex.

Comment: `yourString.match(/:[^\/]+/g);`

Comment: "I tried" is not demonstration of effort. When posting code don't forget portion that normalizes your Url... Also explain why simple `split` is not enough.

Comment: How the hell did this question get three downvotes?!? It's a common question I couldn't find answers online for?

Comment: @Merc I didn't downvote, as I supplied an answer, however I think it's because there's no attempt or effort shown..

Comment: @Merc - If you hover over the downvote button, you can see it says "does not show any research effort".

Comment: Derek added my "research". Your regexp doesn't work BTW, it's easy to look good in a comment.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov added explanation

Comment: I want to see if those people downvoting the question are going to upvote it now since it has explanation and research @Derek朕會功夫

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a look ahead assertion regex for this, like so:

```
(?=:):(.*?)(?=\/|$)
```

working example:

http://regex101.com/r/gO7nO0

Matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  
`workspaceId`
MATCH 2
1.  
`userId`
MATCH 3
1.  
`id`
```

Or better yet, you could simplify and just use:

```
:(\w+)
```

working example:

http://regex101.com/r/nG4mI2

Matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  
`workspaceId`
MATCH 2
1.  
`userId`
MATCH 3
1.  
`id`
```

**Edit:**

Here is a working pure javascript example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BkbrF/2/

Comment: Match groups seem to work for regexp *replacing*, but not for straight match. If you run it in the console, you will see that the result is not what you expect...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what you mean..  here is a working javascript example.. - http://jsfiddle.net/BkbrF/1/ - I will add this to my answer.

Comment: !!! I couldn't get it to work for the life of me using string.match ! Do they work differently? Would you be able to make your code work using `str.match(...)` where `str` is the URL? You are a star!

Answer (score 1):

1: You need to escape the forward-slash like so:

```
\/something\/:workspaceId\/somethingelse\/:userId\/blah\/:id
```

2: Add capturing groups to capture the things you need, like so:

```
\/something\/:(.*?)\/somethingelse\/:(.*?)\/blah\/:(.*?)
```

3: Put the entire thing within javascript Regexp delimiters, `/.../`:

```
/\/something\/:(.*?)\/somethingelse\/:(.*?)\/blah\/:(.*?)/
```

4: execute the regex

```
var rexp = /\/something\/:(.*?)\/somethingelse\/:(.*?)\/blah\/:(.*?)/;
var matched = rexp.exec(string_to_match);
```

You will have:

> matched[0] => entire matched string
>   matched[1] => first capturing group, workspaceId
>   matched[2] => second capturing group, userId
>   matched[3] => third capturing group, id

5: Learn regex from a good online source

**EDIT** To make it even more generic, use this:

```
var rexp = /\/.*?\/:(.*?)\/.*?\/:(.*?)\/.*?\/:(.*?)/;
```

Comment: This is very specific to this string, I was after something generic, have problems with the groupings...

Comment: @Merc I've fixed it, forgot to add capturing groups